# Call NHibernate Repository from HttpApplication.Init()

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

In S#Arch based web application I need to read some data during the application initialization. From the first point, the best place - HttpApplication.Application_Start() or HttpApplication.Init()

But, Application_Start isn't applicable as there is no WebSessionStorage yet. Init() seems isn't fit as well, as there is no NHibernateSession.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you load it (and load only once) app first request?

nhibernate has some problems initialing on Init(), thats why it is on begin_request on s#arp